# Don't know where errors are. How to check in C-free?

Tags: c++

I'm new at programming and I just downloaded C-free 5.0 software. I just compiled a program, it showed that the program has 5 errors. But I can't find a way to see what errors and where. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: My crystal ball is out of order, we need more information...

Comment: Your errors are, where they're supposed to be. Sorry, but with so little information you provided and with such a broad question, I don't know, if you can get any other answer. Have you noticed "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" article?

Comment: I'll try to ask a good question next time. Thanks for commenting though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will probably be in a dock window called "build". Like all other IDEs, you may need to use the menu to open that window first. If the window is already open, scroll up.

The build dock window is the one at the bottom, in this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I compiled my program, and it says 0 error(s), 0 warning(s). But when I run the program, it says 5 errors. And unlike in the screenshot you posted where the error is highlighted, it doesn't highlight the error when I do it.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. Errors when compiling/linking happen when you build the program. Any output like "5 errors" while you run the built program is written by the program itself - it's just doing what you programmed it to do.
Also there is no error highlighted in the screenshot I posted.

Comment: Uh okay. The same program runs fine on microsoft visual c++ 6.0 though. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @anila Then is sounds like the errors are happening while compiling/linking, which you wrote they are not. You should edit the question and add a screenshot of the "errors".

Comment: Ok, I will try. I'm new at stack. Not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: @anila Click "edit" in the question. In the text area set the cursor where you want the image, then above the edit area click the icon to add an image (hover over the icons with the mouse to get a tooltip that explains what they do). Select upload from computer, then select the image. Wait a few seconds for the image and then you should see how it looks in the preview area below.

Comment: Can't. It says I need 10 reputation.